# Meaning of "Your eyes are veiled wit far too many veils..."?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Full context :

> Your eyes are veiled wit far too many veils. Each thing you look upon
>   is but a veil.

Can you explain what it ideologically means , emphasize on first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Literally, a veil is a garment that covers your eyes, and often your whole face. It can have the purpose of hiding your face, preventing you from seeing, or both.

Metaphorically, a "veil" usually signifies something non-physical that either hides something or (figuratively) blinds you to something. For example, a "veiled threat" is a verbal threat "hidden" by non-aggressive words.

In your quotation, it seems to imply that the person has more than one thing that prevents them from "seeing", most likely seeing in the figurative sense (ie comprehending, understanding). The writer is saying that their "eyes" are covered with so many veils that all they see is a veil. Without the context, I couldn't say what the veils represent or what they are trying to see, but an example may be someone who has been told so many lies they are unable to see the truth.